# How to configure Firestore Rules when access via Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I'm (now) aware that Firestore Collection rules only apply when accessed via a Browser/App.
They are not used when Firestore is accessed via a Cloud Function.

While not ideal I can write my own checks within the Cloud Function.

However, how do I keep the Firestore DB secure on the Browser?

If I set up the rules like this, any request made to Firestore from within the Cloud Function fails - I assume because request.auth is null.

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }  
}
```

How do I secure browser access without breaking Cloud Function access??

---

UPDATE

Angular App makes request to Firebase Cloud Function.
The Firebase Cloud Function then calls Firestore.

Rules

```json
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }  
}
```

Code in Cloud Function to get Job from Firestore

```
 import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
 import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
 import { DocumentData, doc, getDoc, getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

// We need to import the 'firebase-admin' package to set claims, verify tokens, etc.
 admin.initializeApp();

 // we use this get access to Firestore etc
 const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 const auth: Auth = getAuth(app);

 const firestore = getFirestore();
 const docRef = doc(firestore, 'jobs', uid);
 const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
 const docData = docSnap.data() as DocumentData | undefined;
```

Make a GET Request to GCF

`GET australia-southeast1/app/jobs`

Returns a 200 and a list of jobs

Change the rules to:

```
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null
    }
  }  
}
```

Make a GET Request to GCF

`GET australia-southeast1/app/jobs`

Request from client returns a 403, with error

`{"code":"permission-denied","message":"Missing or insufficient permissions."}`

> The only change made was to the rules.

Note, the user *is* authenticated at this point, the call to the cloud function happens immediately after login and a Bearer token is sent with the request.

[image]

Comment: Rules are not checked when firestore data is modified from Cloud Functions

Comment: And yet I am getting a permission denied error from Firestore when accessed via Cloud Functions, ONLY when I change the rules to check auth. If I simply return true in the rules, the request passes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I set up the rules like this, any request made to Firestore from within the Cloud Function fails

All operations that access Cloud Firestore which are performed using Cloud Functions, will bypass security rules entirely. Security rules only apply to web and mobile clients.

> I assume because request.auth is null.

Those rules will reject a read or a write operation only when those operations are performed on the client and the user is not authenticated.

**Edit:**

You're getting the following error:

> {"code":"permission-denied","message":"Missing or insufficient permissions."}

Because you're using Firestore from `firebase/firestore` and **not** from the `firebase-admin`. Please note that all the functionality inside Cloud Functions that require Firestore should be obtained via `firebase-admin` with `admin.firestore()`.

Comment: And yet I am getting a permission denied error from Firestore when accessed via Cloud Functions, ONLY when I change the rules to check auth. If I simply return true in the rules, the request passes.

Comment: Where do you get that error? Can you please show us a concrete example?

Comment: I'll post an update tmrw

Comment: Looking forward to seeing it.

Comment: Added some more details

Comment: Thanks for adding more details, it's clear now. So please check my updated answer. Is it ok now?

Comment: Thanks for taking another look @alex-mamo, however that is not the case. The user is  authenticated at this point. After login, the user is redirected to a dashboard that attempts to the load the jobs.  I've updated with a screenshot that shows the requests.

Comment: Removing the need to use both `firebase-admin` and `firebase/app` is something I'll look at again though.

Comment: Yes, please use Firestore through the Firebase Admin and tell me if it works.

Comment: OK, so now, server-side I'm only using `firebase-admin` and things work as expected. Thanks @alex-mamo

Comment: I have edited my answer with the correct solution. So can I help you now with other information?